# How many maximum files per directory on CentOS 5 64bit or Linux RedHat 64bit?

Tags: centos, files, maximum

Now, I have any 20,000 files in single directory. 
How many maximum files per directory on CentOS 64bit ext3?

Answer (score 6):

The number of files in a directory is limited primarily by the maximum file size, divided by the size of a directory entry. As the maximum file size is in the terabytes range, there is no practical limit on a directory size. Depending on what ext3 features you use, performance may degenerate as the directory grows larger.

There is a [limit of 32000 subdirectories](http://zachwaugh.com/2008/11/xt3-filesystem-sub-directory-limit/).

Comment: In redhat 5 using ext3 with the limit of ((32K - 2)) on centos 7 with ext3 I don't see this problem

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-in-a-directory-is-too-many