# Debian 6: how to check if I have some limit on max number of files inside a dir?

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems

I know of fat32 being of 65.000 files per dir, what about linux/debian?

ext4?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many maximum files per directory on CentOS 5 64bit or Linux RedHat 64bit?](http://serverfault.com/questions/77062/how-many-maximum-files-per-directory-on-centos-5-64bit-or-linux-redhat-64bit)

Comment: @sven: there isn't any answer in that question to how many files ext4 can handle per dir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your filesystem. Ext3 has the following limits:

- Maximum number of sub-directories: 32000 (hardcoded)
- Maximum number of *inodes* (maximum number of files and directories on the whole system): the default is calculated based on the volume size in bytes (default number of inodes = V/2^13)

Other filesystems will have different limits, some will limit files inside a dir while others don't. Refer to your filesystem documentation for more info.

You can see some Ext4 limits on [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/104986/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-files-a-file-system-can-contain/104989#104989).

Comment: debian 6 uses ext4 (what i am interested about) anyway +1

Comment: @yes check my comment

Comment: ok! `df -i` shows how many free inode are left, what i wanted (atm i have 44mil inode free, i have some margin xD)

Comment: @yes yes unless you are running a mailserver with Maildir store, no spam filtering and millions of users, you are ok :P

Answer (score 3):

On ext4:

- the subdirectory limit is 64000.
- max number of files 4 billion (specified at filesystem creation time)

Comment: max number of files 4 billion per directory? or 4bil per entire filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, why don't you test your machine?

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
mkdir testdir || exit 1
cd testdir || exit 1

while true
do
  [ $(($i % 1000)) -eq 0 ] && echo "creating file $i"
  touch file.$i || { echo "failed to create file.$i"; exit 1; }
  ((i++))
done
```

Please, please don't run that on a production server.  The system could become very sluggish as it creates massive numbers of files.

Also note that deleting a directory full of many, many thousands of files could also take a very long time (like hours).

Comment: This is an overkill. Somewhere in ext4 specs should be known

Comment: Don't do that, you may end doing a kind of a DDOS on a machine, and depending on the FS you may end using ALL the available inodes.

Comment: And by DDOS I mean DOS.

Comment: Oh heck you guys, it's just a fun experiment to run.  I clearly say don't do it on a production server.  Specs are fine but it's always useful to experiment as well.  Also note that some filesystems get massive performance problems above a certain number of files per dir, this is a good way to detect that.